# Can’t see long alt text

Tags: bug, alt-text

I’m on a network right now that blocks Imgur, and I noticed that long alt text doesn’t show. Instead I see a short, wide white rectangle with a grey border. Here’s an example that should show the problem:

[image: 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890]

Markdown:

```
![1234567890123456789012345678901234567890](https://example.com)
```

Also here’s a screenshot from a revision history that shows this bug:

[image: Screenshot exhibiting the problem]

This happens on everything that I’ve been able to test:

- iOS app
- Mobile Safari

  - Mobile view
  - Desktop view

I am able to get the following code to show alt code in Codepen, so this looks like a Stack Exchange bug to me:

```
<img src="https://example.com" alt="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"></img>
```

Comment: By the way we cannot access your link due to permissions. Put screenshots _in the question_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is the new link visible to you

Comment: Instead of a link, put the screenshot _in the question_. 15k on meta you should know this!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I cannot upload to Imgur right now as it is blocked :/

Comment: Mind if we convert it to imgur for you?

Comment: I see. I have done it for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a WebKit bug, not a Stack Exchange bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It may be true that this is caused by a bug in WebKit, but that doesn’t mean that there’s nothing that Stack Exchange can do to fix it. Long alt text works for me in codepen, but I’m not sure what the difference is between what I wrote and the code used here.

Comment: @Laurel What sort of thing could Stack Exchange do to fix it? The problem is literally your browser not doing HTML properly. Stack Exchange can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

We can confirm from the generated HTML that the alt text is present in full.

If it is not rendered by your browser, you will need to discuss this with the vendor who created it. In your case, that'll be team responsible for *WebKit*.

In the case of the iOS app, I assume WebKit is being used, so again this is something to kick upstream.

- [Similar previous complaints about this using WebKit](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6624-alt-text-not-visible)
- [Possibly related/responsible WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5566)

For what it's worth, I see all of it in Chrome 76 on Windows.